# How to sent text from my C# WinForm program to another program - where the cursor is

Tags: c#, winforms

How to send text from my C# Winforms program to another program where the cursor is

For example: I have in my program `label` that contains `"ABC"`, when I press `'Z'`

the `ABC` will appear where the cursor is standing.

How to do it? What to look for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for Interprocess Communication which can be acheived by WCF in .net.

Try this [Simple Inter-process Communication system for .NET framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/627527/Simple-Inter-process-Communication-system-for-NET)